# x64 asm assign value to a by ref parameter works in Delphi, but not Lazarus Free Pascal

Tags: delphi, assembly, lazarus, freepascal, calling-convention

In the simplified code below, Len is not being assigned.

```
function Test64(const Val: Int64; var Len: Integer): Integer;
begin
asm
  mov           [Len], $1
end;
end;
```

I'm compiling in 64 bit mode.

This works in Delphi (32 bit), though. How do I get it to work in Lazarus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always prefer to be explicit about the registers used to pass parameters when writing asm. It makes it much easier to spot register misuse.

So I would write it like this:

```
function Test64(const Val: Int64; var Len: Integer): Integer;
asm
  mov dword ptr [rdx], $1
end;
```

I suspect that you are actually compiling for x86 because the Delphi x64 compiler does not support mixing Pascal and asm as you do in the question. So, as I understand things, the code in the question does not compile under the Delphi x64 compiler.

You can see that in my code above I am not mixing Pascal and asm. This is a pure asm function. My advice is always to code this way, even on x86. Doing so will allow you to be sure that the compiler does not interfere with your stack and register usage.

In x86 the code would be:

```
function Test64(const Val: Int64; var Len: Integer): Integer;
asm
  mov dword ptr [edx], $1
end;
```

On Windows x64 Microsoft define the ABI and there is only one calling convention. It is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx

The x64 ABI for non Microsoft platforms (the System V x64 ABI) is different. I've assumed you target Windows.

The Delphi x86 ABI is described here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Control

Comment: I get 'Unknown identifier: "RDX"' with that. How do you know Len is set to RDX?

Comment: It's rdx because the x64 Windows abi specifies that. If rdx is not recognised then I think you are compiling for x86.

Comment: I assume that the reason I can use [var_name] to read a variable but not write it is due to the compiler's interpreting [var_name] differently for read / write? After all, both work in Delphi (x86), but not Lazarus (x64 mode).

Comment: I don't know about that. I don't see why that would be so. However, I cannot stress enough that you should not use parameter names or named pascal local vars in asm code. It invariably leads to pain. Once you start writing asm you need to know which registers you use, how much stack space you use and so on. To me it's all or nothing. Half way houses with use of pascal local var names don't work out.

Comment: Factor in also the fact that you want to write code for two compilers. The more complex you make it the more likely that you hit differences between the compilers. And with asm there are more differences than with pascal. Another argument in favour of explicit register and stack usage.

Comment: Interestingly we discussed a lot of these issues at a recent question of yours where you used a pascal label in asm rather than an asm label. I really cannot state this with enough emphasis. Mixing pascal and asm leads to pain.

Comment: David, I remember. I didn't associate labels with variable names. I understand now and have already altered all ASM code to pure registers, pure asm.

Comment: Sure, that was pascal labels rather than variables but I see the parallel in anything mixing pascal and asm. Anyway, interesting subject. Thanks for asking!

Comment: The only conversion to pure asm aspect I haven't figured out yet is if the 1st param is a float. ST(0) throws a size error.

Comment: x64 doesn't use the x87 fpu. It uses sse registers instead. The link to MSDN tells you what you need to know. Floating point values come in XMM0-3. On x86 register calling convention, floating point values are pushed onto the stack. Again documented in the links I gave you. You can always get the compiler to show you how by observing the code it generates to pass and retrieve parameters.

Comment: I know. I should have qualified that I was referring to Delphi 32 code in this case.

Comment: I did go through the links you sent for 64 bit, and all my 64 bit asm is pure asm now. I only got stuck on floats with my 32 bit asm.

Comment: For that you need the final link to the Emba docs. But let the compiler show you how. That will help you understand the docs.

Comment: How to you define constants in ASM while keeping the code pure ASM? I haven't been able to find answer to this.

Comment: You can define constants as Pascal typed constants. Then you refer to them by name.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working because it is giving an error that indicates RIP is required, which means the compiler isn't baking the constants in, but is looking them up in memory.

Comment: It's hard to comment without seeing the code, and in comments to another answer. Perhaps a new question is needed.